# AES encryption and decryption not working properly

Tags: java, ios, swift, encryption, aes

I am trying to decrypt data encrypted using AES algorithm on backend. The data came after decryption is not complete.

Backend code to encrypt data (written in JAVA)

```
class AES {

    // Class private variables
    private static final String SALT = "t-*(b`.:#H$^[)7M^p&*@E]";

    // This method use to encrypt to string
    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String learnerId) {
        try {

            EncryptionKey encryptionKey = getGenerateSecretKey(learnerId);
//            System.out.println("" + encryptionKey.ivspec + ":" + encryptionKey.secretKey.toString());
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, encryptionKey.secretKey, encryptionKey.ivspec);
            // Return encrypted string
            byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
//            System.out.println("encryptedOutput:" + output.toString());
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(output);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException |
                 BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    // This method use to decrypt to string
    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String learnerId) {
        try {

            EncryptionKey encryptionKey = getGenerateSecretKey(learnerId);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, encryptionKey.secretKey, encryptionKey.ivspec);
            // Return decrypted string
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException |
                 BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }


    private static AES.EncryptionKey getGenerateSecretKey(String learnerId) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        // Create default byte array
        byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        // Create SecretKeyFactory object
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(learnerId.toCharArray(), SALT.getBytes(),  10000, 128);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
        System.out.println("Key:" + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(tmp.getEncoded()));
        return new EncryptionKey(ivspec, secretKey);
    }

    // AES secret key
//    public static SecretKey getAESKey(int keysize) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
//        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
//        keyGen.init(keysize);
//        return keyGen.generateKey();
//    }


    private static class EncryptionKey {
        public final IvParameterSpec ivspec;
        public final SecretKeySpec secretKey;

        public EncryptionKey(IvParameterSpec ivspec, SecretKeySpec secretKey) {
            this.ivspec = ivspec;
            this.secretKey = secretKey;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        String valueToEncrypt = "Hello World!";
        String encryptedValue = encrypt(valueToEncrypt, "15c20b4babfec000");
        String decryptedValue = decrypt(encryptedValue, "15c20b4babfec000");
        System.out.println("valueToEncrypt:" + valueToEncrypt);
        System.out.println("encryptedValue:" + encryptedValue);
        System.out.println("decryptedValue:" + decryptedValue);
//        getGenerateSecretKey("15c20b4babfec000");
    }
}
```

**output:
valueToEncrypt:Hello World!
encryptedValue:61VkIxCEBJJ46QF6VPwpXg==
decryptedValue:Hello World!
**

Frontend Code written in Swift

```
static func testingEncryption() -> Bool {
        let password: [UInt8] = Array("15c20b4babfec000".utf8)
        let salt: [UInt8] = Array(EncryptionKeys.saltKeyLoEncryption.utf8)
        do {
            /* Generate a key from a `password`. Optional if you already have a key */
            let key = try PKCS5.PBKDF2(
                password: password,
                salt: salt,
                iterations: 10_000,
                keyLength: 16, /* AES-256 */
                variant: .sha256
            ).calculate()
            Log.debug("AES key \n \(String(describing: key.toBase64()))")
            //             Generate random IV value. IV is public value. Either need to generate, or get it from elsewhere
            //            let iv = AES.randomIV(AES.blockSize)
            //            let iv = Array(hex: "4963b7334a46352623252955df21d7f3")
            let iv: [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0E]
//          let newKey: [UInt8] = [
//              0x2B, 0x7E, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xAE, 0xD2, 0xA6,
//              0xAB, 0xF7, 0x97, 0x07, 0xA5, 0x16, 0x18, 0x63
//          ]
            /* AES cryptor instance */
            let aes = try AES(key: key, blockMode: CBC(iv: iv), padding: .pkcs5)
            /* Encrypt Data */
//          let inputData = "Subham Tyagi".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
//          let encryptedBytes = try aes.encrypt(inputData.bytes)
//            let encryptedData = Data(encryptedBytes)
//          Log.debug("AES encrypted data \(encryptedData.base64EncodedString())")
            /* Decrypt Data */

            if let newData = Data(base64Encoded: "61VkIxCEBJJ46QF6VPwpXg==") {
                let decryptedBytes = try aes.decrypt(newData.bytes)
                let decryptedData = Data(decryptedBytes)
                Log.debug("AES decrypted data \(String(describing: String(data: decryptedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)))")
            }
        } catch AES.Error.invalidKeySize {
            Log.error("encryption decryption failed due to invalidKeySize")
        } catch AES.Error.dataPaddingRequired {
            Log.error("encryption decryption failed dataPaddingRequired ")
        } catch AES.Error.invalidData {
            Log.error("encryption decryption failed invalid data")
        } catch CryptoSwift.CBC.Error.invalidInitializationVector {
            Log.error("encryption decryption failed invalidInitializationVector")
        } catch {
            Log.error("encryption decryption failed \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return true
    }
```

**output:
AES decrypted data Optional("Hello ")**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is presumably due to the different IV for encryption and decryption. In the Java code (encryption) the last byte is 0x00, while in the Swift code (decryption) the last byte is 0x0E. Fix: Use the same IV in both codes, i.e. for encryption and decryption.

Comment: The incorrect last byte of the IV leads to a corruption of the last padding byte to 0x0a (instead of 0x04) of the decrypted data. Obviously, the Swift code does not check whether the padding bytes are uniform (which is actually a shortcoming) and simply uses the last padding byte to determine the size of the padding, so that the unpadding cuts off 0x0a-0x04=0x06 bytes too much (which turns `Hello World!` into `Hello `).

Comment: **Security warning**: Please DO NOT USE the code above because it is **UNSECURE** because it uses a fixed/static IV and salt. Better use random generated IV and salt and prepend them to the ciphertext.

Comment: `SALT.getBytes()` in Java is very bad style as it depends on the system charset what you get. If you want to define bytes do so and don't misuse Strings for doing so.

Comment: thanks @Topaco this has fixed the bug. I have made iv same used in encryption.

Comment: @MichaelFehr thanks for your input; we definitely will vary the IV to make it more secure and make most use of CBC.